# iOS simulator crashes when recreated table view cell is deleted

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to app development, and I've created a very simple To-Do List app using XCode and Swift.  But for some reason, when the user deletes a task, creates it again under the same name, and then deletes that cell, the iOS simulator crashes with the exception code:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)
```

Here's the backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xb80ca, 0x000000010a4ff00b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
frame #0: 0x000000010a4ff00b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
frame #1: 0x00000001092318be UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
frame #2: 0x0000000109338410 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
frame #3: 0x00000001093377df UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
frame #4: 0x0000000109277308 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
frame #5: 0x0000000109277c33 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
frame #6: 0x00000001092449b1 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
frame #7: 0x0000000109251a7d UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
frame #8: 0x000000010922d103 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
frame #9: 0x00000001088da551 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
frame #10: 0x00000001088d041d CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
frame #11: 0x00000001088cfa54 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 868
frame #12: 0x00000001088cf486 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
frame #13: 0x000000010ca9b9f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
frame #14: 0x0000000109230420 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
* frame #15: 0x00000001087bb0fe swift course 013 todo list`top_level_code + 78 at AppDelegate.swift:12
frame #16: 0x00000001087bb13a swift course 013 todo list`main + 42 at AppDelegate.swift:0
frame #17: 0x000000010acc2145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

And the relevant code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var toDoListTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoList") != nil {

        toDoList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoList") as [String]

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return toDoList.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        toDoList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")

        toDoListTable.reloadData()

    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    toDoListTable.reloadData()

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Learn how to get a proper exception message and exception stack trace.  ("(lldb)" is not an error message, that's the debugger prompt.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited now with the exception code and backtrace @Hot Licks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you should try implementing UITableViewDataSource in UIViewControler.swift! It worked for me. Example:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete{
   //Array.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tdArr, forKey: "tdArr")

    tableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return //Array.count
}
```